# how delphi article spinner

Tags: delphi

I have an article with 500 words
I need to change some words in it
can you give an example ?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
Update: String;
begin
 Update := StringReplace(Memo1.Lines.Text, 'Hi', 'Hello', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
 memo2.Lines.Add(Update);
end;
```

Comment: Well, you seem to have the general idea, so what's your problem exactly?

Comment: What is this about a *spinner*? I don't see one and have no idea why it is being mentioned or tagged. The title of your question makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 1):

You add (append, to be exact) the result of the function to the memo, you don't *replace* it.

Do something like this:

```
Update := StringReplace(Memo1.Lines.Text, 'Hi', 'Hello', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
Memo1.Lines.Text := Update;
```

Comment: Personally, I would switch to `TRichEdit` and use its `FindText()` method and `SelText` property to replace words inline instead of reading/writing the entire `Text` as a whole.

Comment: @Remy: but that would not be an answer to this question. Apparently he is satisfied with appending, so replacing should be fine too. And I am not sure if updating the text as whole is not faster than editing one by one inside a memo or richedit. We already know there are some 500 words, so the text can't be too large.